# Golang compile environment variable into binary

Tags: go

If I compile this program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var version = os.Getenv("VERSION")

func main() {
    fmt.Println(version)
}
```

It prints the env var when I run it

```
VERSION="0.123" ./example
> 0.123
```

Is there a way to compile the env var into the binary, for example:

```
VERSION="0.123" go build example.go
```

Then get the same output when I run

```
./example
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Go 1.5 and above edit:**

As of now, the syntax has changed.

On Unix use:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.Version=$VERSION"
```

On Windows use:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.Version=%VERSION%"
```

---

This is what `-X` linker flag is for. In your case, you would do

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.Version $VERSION"
```

**Edit:** on Windows this would be

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.Version %VERSION%"
```

[More info in the linker docs](https://golang.org/cmd/link/).

Comment: +1 Really cool, I didn't know about this. One note: on Windows you have to write `go build -ldflags "-X main.Version %VERSION%"`

Comment: @icza Thanks, added Windows version to the answer.

Comment: Compiler complains about the syntax above `link: warning: option -X main.Version 0.2 may not work in future releases; use -X main.Version=0.2`. Also, I want to point out that you can set a default value when the env variable is not passed in, set `var Version = 0.1` in `example.go`

Comment: @Muddz `-ldflags "-X a=1 -X b=2"`.

Comment: I can't getting it to work. Not even a simple line as `-ldflags "-X main.test=Hello"` with a declared `var test string` is doing anything. When I run my program as an .exe on windows I also log the `test` variable to a .txt file to see if it works, but ´test` variable is just an empty string

Comment: @Ainar-G forgot to mention I'm typing these commands in Golands `Program Arguments` under the Run Configurations page

Comment: I'm not using IDEs, I use vim. Search through your IDE's documentation.

Comment: this is a cool trick to know, i didn't know that. thanks. but the question is about how to set the env variable at build time. does anyone has a correct answer?

Answer (score 14):

Ainer-G's answer led me to the right place, but it wasn't a full code sample answering the question. A couple of changes were required:

1. Declare the version as `var version string`
2. Compile with `-X main.version=$VERSION`

Here's the full code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var version string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(version)
}
```

Now compile with

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.version=$VERSION"
```

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/B3IuewBqY67 example with the behavior I wanted. Notice that `go build` behaves different to `go run`?

Comment: @Muddz Same basic approach. If you also have a `var date string`, then compile with `-ldflags "-X main.version=$VERSION -X main.date=$DATE"`

Answer (score 5):

There is an [`os.Setenv()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Setenv) function which you can use to set environment variables.

So you can start your application by setting the environment variable like this:

```
func init() {
    os.Setenv("VERSION", "0.123")
}
```

If you don't want to do this by "hand", you could create a tool for this which would read the current value of the `VERSION` environment variable and generate a `.go` source file in your package containing exactly like the code above (except using the current value of the `VERSION` environment variable). You can run such code generation by issuing the `go generate` command.

Read the [**Generating code**](http://blog.golang.org/generate) blog post for more details about `go generate`.