# Shell variable in a string passed with -ldflags to the Go compiler is not expanded

Tags: bash, go, quoting

I'm trying to get a simple build bash script to work and can't get the date as an argument. What am I missing here? Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
buildDate=$(date)
go build -ldflags='-X main.buildTimestamp=$buildDate' main.go
```

Output: `Build: $buildDate`

Comment: @Adrian, I'm inclined to think the question still deserves the `go` tag as the toolchain has a certain quirk for dealing with spaces in argument passed to `-*flags`, which I touched upon in my answer.

Comment: You are right, this will be handy for other fellow Gophers. Added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [the documentation on a POSIX-compatible shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02):

> 2.2.2 Single-Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in single-quotes ( `''` ) shall preserve the literal value of each character within the single-quotes. A single-quote cannot occur within single-quotes.

So, in your particular case, `bash` breaks the `go build …` command into words and performs string substitution before actually executing the command.

As per string substitution rules, the text enclosed with single quotes is taken literally, so after the expansion the shell looks up the `go` command and executes it pasing it the tree resulting arguments, which are, in order: `build`, `-ldflags=-X main.buildTimestamp=$buildDate` and `main.go`.

Since the Go toolchain does not invoke shell anywhere in its course of work, the literal text `$buildDate` gets passed unmodified to the compiler.

If the format of your build date does not include whitespace, the easiest fix is to just replace the single quotes with double quotes.

If you need to embed spaces in there, it gets a little bit more tricky but not too much — to cite the output of `go build help`:

> The `-asmflags`, `-gccgoflags`, `-gcflags`, and `-ldflags` flags
>   accept a space-separated list of arguments to pass
>   to an underlying tool during the build.
>   *To embed spaces in an element in the list, surround
>   it with either single or double quotes.*
>   <…>

In other words, the command-line argument parser considers pairs of `"`s and `'`s to implement argument grouping, and in your case you could do

```
go build -ldflags="-X main.buildTimestamp='$buildDate'" main.go
```

so that the shell strips out the outer double quotes *and* substitutes `$buildDate` for its value — as per the rules of string substitution for the case of double quotes.
Hence, if your build date format includes spaces, like in, say, `Tue, 12 May 2020 20:53:16 +0300`, the `go` command would receive the following three arguments, in order: `build`, `-ldflags=-X main.buildTimestamp='Tue, 12 May 2020 20:53:16 +0300'` and `main.go`, and would take care of those single quotes by itself.

Comment: Thanks! Executed the script after replacing the single quotes for double and get the list of command arguments of go build.

Comment: 1) You might have a more complex problem if your build date string includes whitespace; 2) I'd recommend to first play with the invocation by hand in a shell prompt.

Comment: Ineed, the date output was with spaces. Changed it to date -u +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M and worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers above and other refs (link below),

here is my solution for append build datetime into golang executable:

```
## build.sh / CLI
go build -ldflags="-X 'main.build_version=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")'" main.go
```

```
/* main.go */

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var build_version string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(build_version)
}
```

ref:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications
2. [Golang compile environment variable into binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459102/golang-compile-environment-variable-into-binary)